# Polymer: Data binding breaking with on-tap handler on a button within a dom-repeat

Tags: polymer

Ran into an issue here with Polymer's data binding functionality when used in conjunction with dom-repeat.  I'm wondering what I'm missing in order to make this work.

Data binding seems to work fine in some cases with the repeat element, e.g. with input boxes.  However, using an on-tap event on a button and editing a field on the associated item object doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Here is my SSCCE (Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vof1nYdDFR4Jg4ZXL9DI?p=preview):

```
index.html
==========
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="dummy_element.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Click the "Toggle" button to toggle between Edit and View modes.</p>
    <dummy-element></dummy-element>
  </body>
</html>

dummy_element.html
==================
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="dummy-element">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{records}}">
      <p>
        <span hidden="{{item.editing}}">View mode: {{item.value}}</span>
        <span hidden="{{!item.editing}}">Edit mode: <input value="{{item.value}}" /></span>
        <button on-tap="onTap">Toggle</button>
      </p>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'dummy-element',
        properties: {
            records: {
                type: Array,
                value: function () {
                    return [
                        {value: '#1', editing: false},
                        {value: '#2', editing: true},
                    ];
                },
            },
        },
        onTap: function (e) {
            e.model.item.editing = !e.model.item.editing;
            console.log('Editing:', e.model.item.editing);
        },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

My intent: my click handler on the Toggle buttons should toggling the "editing" flag between true and false for the row in question, and the UI should automatically update to reflect the change.

What happens: while the underlying model seems to change, the UI does not get redrawn.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues. First, in the `onTap` handler you need to use the [Polymer API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) to mutate the object in the array.

```
onTap: function (e) {
    this.set("records." +e.model.index +".editing", !e.model.item.editing);
    console.log('Editing:', e.model.item.editing);
},
```

As Scarygami pointed out in the comments, `e.model` has its own `set`. So the above could also be simplified to:

```
onTap: function (e) {
    e.model.set("item.editing", !e.model.item.editing);
    console.log('Editing:', e.model.item.editing);
},
```

Second, for the data-binding to work properely on the native `input` element, you  have to [specify the target host event](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html).

```
<input value="{{item.value::input}}" />
```

Here's a [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/kePJGsujUQOpqLZShy7c?p=preview) to a fork of your plunker that works.

Comment: Knew about the input issue; that was laziness. :-)  But the correct Polymer API I did not know.  ...looks like I skimmed the data binding section a little too lightly.  Thank you!  This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I noticed you only asked about the tap handler, but the input thing caught my eye and was an easy fix. Anyway, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Two small notes:
`this.set`accepts arrays, so you could do `this.set(['records', e.model.index, 'editing'], ...)`
Also `e.model` comes its own set function, so you could also do `e.model.set('item.editing', ...)`

Comment: @Scarygami I wasn't aware of the `set` function in model. Thanks for pointing that out. That removes the issue of finding the array index.